# Puppeteer - How To Click and Type by label text?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to use Puppeteer to click on a field and type text into it.

```
<label for="ext-gen572" style="width:180px;" class="x-form-item-label" id="ext-gen703">Old Password：</label>`
`<input type="password" autocomplete="off" data-flag="true" id="ext-gen572" name="ext-gen572" class="x-form-text x-form-field" size="20" maxlength="64">`
```

```
<label for="ext-gen573" style="width:180px;" class="x-form-item-label" id="ext-gen706">New Password：</label>
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" data-flag="true" id="ext-gen573" name="ext-gen573" class="x-form-text x-form-field x-form-invalid" size="20" maxlength="64">
```

All field ids are dynamic and they go with value of labels.
There are several type="password" elements.
So the only way to recognize the field is text of label.
I will so appreciate if someone can help.

This is my code below. But nothing happened..

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
        const elements = [...document.queryselectorall('label')];
        const targetelement = elements.find(e => e.contains == 'Old Password：');
        if (targetelement) targetelement.click();
    });
```

Comment: `queryselectorall` should be `querySelectorAll`. `e.contains == 'Old Password：'` should be `e.contains("Old Password:")`. Try running this in the browser and you should see the problematic behavior--you're comparing an uncalled function with a string. Also, I don't think dispatching an untrusted `click()` will give focus on the element, if that's what you want to do. Use `.focus()` or a trusted Puppeteer method. If those fixes don't work, please share a [mcve], preferably with the site itself and your complete (but minimal) code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

via full contents of the label :

```
let text = 'Old Password：';
let selector = "xpath/" + `//label[text()='${text}']`;

let input = await page.waitForSelector(selector); 
await input.click(); 
await page.keyboard.type('Test', { delay: 10 });
```

via partial contents of the label:

```js
let text = 'Old';
let selector = 'xpath/' + `//label[contains(.,'${text}')]`;

let input = await page.waitForSelector(selector); 
await input.click(); 
await page.keyboard.type('Test', { delay: 10 });
```

you could also use `x-form-invalid` class that is unique to *New password* for the above case

```js
let input = await page.waitForSelector('input[class*=x-form-invalid]'); // new password 
await input.click(); 
await page.keyboard.type('Test', { delay: 10 })
```

```js
let input = await page.waitForSelector('input:not(.x-form-invalid)'); // old password
await input.click(); 
await page.keyboard.type('Test', { delay: 10 })
```

Comment: why it shows input.click() is not a function if I don't want to use await?

Comment: @AndyYu [await](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp) is used to wait for the promise to be resolved in async functions. In this case it waits for the `<label>` to be loaded, if it isn't loaded, it isn't there so you cant click it and so you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath` instead (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp):

```js
const labelOldPass = await page.waitForXPath("//label[contains(text(), 'Old Password：')]");
await labelOldPass.click();
```